# Excel: Derive Table column name with formula

Tags: excel

I have an Excel table called `weather_data` and it has a column for each month, e.g. "Jan", "Feb", etc.

In another sheet, I have one column with various dates listed and in a second column I want to use a formula to extract data from `weather_data`. Right now this second table looks like this:

```
Date    Avg_Temp
Jun 
Jul 
Aug
```

E.g. if I want to fill in the first entry under `Avg_Temp` using data from `weather_data`, which again has a column for each month, I could manually enter `=AVERAGE(weather_data[Jun])`. However, I was hoping I could make the column reference (`Jun` in this case) formula driven from the Date column, so I could do something like `=AVERAGE(weather_data[A2])` and copy it down.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your weather_table starts with January in column 1 and has December in column 12, you can do a formula like this in B2 and copy down:

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(weather_data,0,MONTH("1/"&A2)))
```

[image]

This has two interesting parts. The 0 in the row argument of the INDEX formula means to select the entire column. And munging "1/" with the month text in column 1 converts it to a date that can be read by the MONTH function, which then returns the month's number. This is used as the column argument of the INDEX function.

EDIT: Here's one that matches the three-letter month abbreviation in column A of your summary sheet to those in the table headers. This removes the requirement that the table contain only ordered months:

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(weather_data,0,MATCH(A2,weather_data[#Headers],0)))
```

If you wanted to take it a step further and match on just a part of the table header, [I wrote a post](http://yoursumbuddy.com/two-dimensional-index-match-formula-with-variable-length-lookup/) about that.

Comment: `=1/"june"` gives `#VALUE!` in Excel 2010

Comment: @Aprillion, That's true. But that's not what's in the formula.

Comment: @Aprillion, It is cool, isn't it? I read it on Contextures blog a while back, and it always takes a while to remember how it works.

Comment: Thanks Doug! I haven't tried this yet, but from looking at what you posted, it appears to me that this does not leverage the column names in the Table feature of recent Excel versions (2007+ I think ).  `weather_data` described in my question is formatted this way. As a result, I think that if I used your approach, and then added a new column somewhere in `weather_data` this would not work, since you're essentially deriving a hard offset using `MONTH("1/june")`. Does that sound right? Thanks again.

Comment: That is true. I'll add an option.

Comment: Boo. I did not mean to give this a down vote, but it's not letting me change my answer. @DougGlancy